# Haskell - Passing argument to map function?

Tags: haskell

Basic question... I wish to map over a list and apply a function to each element, however I want to execute this from another function:

```
functionOne :: Int -> Int -> Int --Add x to each element of the list
functionOne element x = element + x 

functionTwo :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int]
functionTwo list fOne = map list fOne ave --map list by applying functionOne with ave as x
   where 
     ave = ((sum list) / length list)
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
functionTwo :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int]
functionTwo list fOne = map (\el -> fOne el ave) list
   where 
     ave = sum list `div` length list
```

Above, we use the anonymous function `(\el -> fOne el ave)`, which is the function mapping each `el` to `fOne el ave`. In this way, we fix the second argument of `fOne` to the wanted value.

Alternatively,

```
functionTwo :: [Int] -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int]
functionTwo list fOne = map (flip fOne ave) list
   where 
     ave = sum list `div` length list
```

Note `div` for integer division, `/` only works on floating point numbers.

`flip f` is the same function as `f`, but with the first two arguments in the other order.

Also possible: `` map (`fOne` ave) list ``.

Comment: Can you explain, from your first example, what '(\el -> fOne el ave)' is doing? then i can accept

Comment: @barbrac That's the syntax for a function. It's `\PARAMETER -> BODY`, i.e. in this case it's a function taking a value (`el`) and returning `fOne el ave`.

Comment: Why flip? Addition is commutative, so just `map (fOne ave) list`.

Comment: @amalloy Addition is, but I think the OP wanted the general case, since she specified "with ave as x".